# Running a TCL/Expect Script permanently

Tags: windows-services, tcl, expect

Is there a way of running a TCL/Expect script permanently (it's a loop), in the background?

I'm using the Windows Task Scheduler, but the script stops, as soon as the expect part comes up... If i run it manually, it works. Only starting it "on Startup" and "hidden" seems to mess things up...

I looked at the Dev Kit "Service" possibility, but i don't know how to build the TCL App. Would this be the best option?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could be due to an ugly interaction between the debugging mode that Expect uses under the covers and the way that Windows Services work. Tricky. And _far_ out of my area of expertise.

Comment: if you had to run this script, how would you try to run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually used a loop and started it with Windows Task Scheduler.
The problem was, the ssh connection wanted to verify the ssh finger-print.